# Page displaying 1st post from a range of custom tax?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

Is it possible to have a page display the 1st post from each category from a custom taxonomy?

e.g custom tax called gallery-section, within that it has a range of categories, i.e Gallery 1, Gallery 2 etc.

The page needs to show the 1st post from each of those categories, e.g the 1st post from Gallery 1, Gallery 2 etc. So essentially a page for navigating to each category area.

Currently i’ve only gone this way but its not very dynamic, just by hand putting in each category.

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'gallery-section','gallery-area' => ‘gallery-1','posts_per_page' => '1') ); ?> 

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col span_1_of_4 gallery_block">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>

        </div>

         <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?> 



<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'gallery-section','gallery-area' => ‘gallery-2','posts_per_page' => '1') ); ?> 

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col span_1_of_4 gallery_block">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>

        </div>

         <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Hope i’ve explained that well enough..

Answer (score 0):

If I got it well, something like snippet below should would do what you want.

I assume there are four items in your 'gallery-area' taxonomy and that the class you apply to your div has to vary accordingly (i.e. span_1_of_4 has to become span_2_of_4, etc.).

```
<?php 
$gt_args = array('fields' => 'ids');
$terms = get_terms('gallery-area', $gt_args); //retrieve ID of the terms of 'gallery-area' taxonomy
$counter = 1;

foreach ($terms as $term){ //for each term (i.e. gallery-area-1, 2, 3 and 4) contained in $terms

    $gp_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'gallery-section',
                    'gallery-area' => $term ,
                    );
    $all_posts = get_posts( $gp_args ); //get all posts  
    $cover_post = $all_posts[0]; // take only the first one

    echo '<div class="col span_' . $counter . '_of_4 gallery_block">';
?>
              <a href="<?php get_permalink($cover_post->ID); ?>"> //$cover_post is a post object 
              <?php $cover_post->post_title ?>
              </a>

          </div>
<?php
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

Note that `$cover_post` is a [post object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post);

**EDIT** Term IDs might not work like this in get_post. You may rather have to try with the following parameters instead of those above. Let me know..

```
    $gp_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'gallery-section',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'gallery-area',
                                                    'terms' => $term, 
                                                 ),
                                        ),
                    );
```

Comment: I've just edited the main code box, `$counter` should be defined outside the `forearch` loop...

Comment: Thank you for this, the counter is not actually needed that was just a style name. The query itself doesn’t work :( First one loads but nothing, second one result in a white page :(

Comment: I had forgotten a closing parenthesis in the second one. Had you seen it ? If not try again the second one, I have updated the code above.

Comment: Also, when having a white page because of a script issue, you want to know what's happening to make the debugging process easier. To do so, [set WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to `true` in the config.php file. Once the issue is fixed, you can set it back to `false`. If above snippet had to fail again, please report here the error message that is getting displayed.